# Polymer core-media-query element for responsive layouts

Tags: html, media-queries, polymer

I'm currently struggling with setting up a responsive web page using the core-media-query element from polymer. I have a simple div container with two child-elements which i want to be aligned horizontally on large screens and vertically on small screens (eg. phones). I played around with the [Auto-vertical example](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#auto-vertical) from the documentation but didn't get it to work for me.

I also tried a different approach:

```
<core-media-query query="max-width: 640px" queryMatches="{{phoneScreen}}"></core-media-query>
<div layout {{phoneScreen ? vertical : horizontal}}>
  <div>Alpha</div>
  <div>Beta</div>
  <div>Gamma</div>
</div>
```

But this also doesn't seem to work for me.

Anyone have an idea on how to properly use the `core-media-query`-Element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example. There's a live version at http://jsbin.com/lufewa (I can't embed this using the SO code runner, because you can't resize the output window.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer core-media-query Demo</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">

    <template is="auto-binding">
      <core-media-query query="max-width: 640px" queryMatches="{{phoneScreen}}"></core-media-query>
      <div layout vertical?="{{phoneScreen}}" horizontal?="{{!phoneScreen}}">
        <div>Alpha</div>
        <div>Beta</div>
        <div>Gamma</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't think the `{{phoneScreen ? vertical : horizontal}}` you're trying to use will work in general for including/omitting boolean attributes.

My example pretty closely matches what's [in the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#auto-vertical), and I'd imagine if you couldn't get it working originally, it might have been because it wasn't part of a Polymer element and wasn't wrapped in a [`<template is="auto-binding">`](https://blog.polymer-project.org/howto/2014/09/11/template-is-autobinding/)?

Comment: The example website doesn't work for me in Chrome, due to a cross-site security restriction.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I pasted in the wrong jsbin URL. I've updated the post to reflect the correct URL, which is http://jsbin.com/lufewa

Comment: Fixed, though the answer only applies to Polymer 0.5.